# Google plus share with dynamic content image javascript

Tags: javascript, image, google-plus

I need to post comments to google plus from my website . I used one script its working fine to text  . But I want to display image also.

I have used following code :-

```
(function() {
               var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
               po.src = 'http://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
               var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
             })();

         var cid = 'My console developer id .apps.googleusercontent.com';

         var options = {
                    contenturl: 'http://www.google.com',
                    contentdeeplinkid: '/pages',
                    clientid: cid,
                    cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                    prefilltext: 'Hai happy friday<img src="fgdhj"/>',
                    calltoactionurl: 'http://www.google.com'
                  };
                  // Call the render method when appropriate within your app to display
                  // the button.
                  gapi.interactivepost.render('sharePost', options);
```

How can  I display the image ? Pleasee help me .

Answer (score 0):

You can prefill text, not HTML. You can insert images into the comment field of any Google+ post, programmatic or not. You can link to pages that have an embedded image and you can set the schema.org microdata for that page to suggest using a particular image.